# Where can I download AjaxControlToolkit 4.1.50927?

Tags: download, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I was lead here:

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/AjaxControlToolkit/4.1.50927

but I can find no download links.  Where can I download this?  I've already downloaded NuGet.  Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Once you install NuGet and it becomes integrated into VS2010, you right-click on the project and click Manage NuGet Packages.  You then have to search for what you want and install it.